# why this is infinite loop? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Creating an array of fibonachi numbers:

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var list = [1,1];
  var next = list[list.length-1] + list[list.length-2];

  while (true) {
    if (next<=num) {
      list.push(next);
    } else {
    return list;
    }
  }
}

sumFibs(10);
```

This gives me infinite loop.

If I add `next = list[list.length-1] + list[list.length-2];` after `list.push(next);` it works fine.
Why?

Comment: You only call your function once and there is no incrementation within your loop. num ALWAYS = 10 and next ALWAYS = list[list.length-1] + list[list.length-2]; so...it will go on for ever. As you note, when you add incrementation within the while loop it works as it should.

Comment: If you modify neither `next` nor `num` in the body of the loop, how could the condition `next <= num` ever switch from being true to being false? *Of course* you have an infinite loop.

Comment: You only assign to the `next` variable once, outside of the loop, so nothing changes inside the loop to ever fufill the return condition. BTW, you should use that condition as the condition for the `while` loop, instead of `true`, and return after the loop.

Comment: `next` is a Primitive value so it's not changing. The length of `list` is changing as you're pushing onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` variable does not update every time you reference it. If it did, imagine how confusing programs would be.

You can move the evaluation of the last members of the list to the loop.

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var list = [1, 1];
  var next = list[list.length - 1] + list[list.length - 2];

  while (true) {
    if (next <= num) {
      list.push(next);
      next = list[list.length - 1] + list[list.length - 2]
    } else {
      return list;
    }
  }
}

console.log(sumFibs(10));
```

Here's a different implementation that doesn't rely on a loop.

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  return f(num, [1, 1]);

  function f(n, arr) {
    var next = arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2];
    return next <= num ? f(n, arr.concat(next)) : arr;
  }
}

console.log(sumFibs(10));
```